# Django field choices not properly updating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models, one that loads the other model it's titles in a choice field dynamically. I fixed it so far that if I add a new object to the model which the titles are used from by updating the choice list in the init method, the choice list gets updated immediately. However when I decide to choose it as option and save it I get: Select a valid choice. example is not one of the available choices. When I restart the server it does work, what I did:

model:

```
class Assessment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES = ()
    SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES_LIST = []

    for sRequirement in SpecificRequirements.objects.all():
        SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES_LIST.append((sRequirement.title, sRequirement.title))

    SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES = SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES_LIST

    sRequirementChoice = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES,
                                default='')
```

forms:

```
class AssessmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
        fields = ['title', 'sRequirementChoice']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AssessmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES_LIST = []

        for sRequirement in SpecificRequirements.objects.all():
            SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES_LIST.append((sRequirement.title, sRequirement.title))

        SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES = SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES_LIST

        self.fields['sRequirementChoice'].choices = SPECIFIC_REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why aren't you using a ForeignKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how Model choices work. You are not supposed to populate choices dynamically in models.

You should consider using a ForeignKey relation with `SpecificRequirements` in your model.

Comment: Could you guide me into the right direction with an example or link to an example please?

Comment: Sorry for the late question ,but does this also account for admin choice list? I basically want the choicelist to appear in my django admin under the change_form of assessments

Comment: When you use foreignkeys, choicelist is automatically generated for you both in admin and modelforms.

Comment: Got it working, you got me in the right direction thanks once again!